# FCM onWrite() function firing twice and sending two notifications?

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am having issues sending multiple FCM notifications in my iOS app.

I am using Firebase and it's Realtime Database Trigger function, and am able to trigger the Firebase code when a new node is added to the database and when the node is updated.

The problem is that the first time the function runs on write, it runs twice and sends two notifications.

When a node is updated it only runs once and sends only 1 notification, which is the expected behavior.

Below is my javascript code and JSON structure of the database write.

Can anyone please shed any light onto why my function might be fired twice?

```js
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require('firebase-admin')
var userDeviceToken = ""
var sharedUserID = ""

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  databaseURL: "https://userlocation-aba20.firebaseio.com/"
});


var payloadStart = {
  notification: {
    title: "Name of App",
    body: "Someone has shared a journey with you."
  },
};

var options = {
  priority: "high"
}

var payloadEnd = {
  notification: {
    title: "Name of App",
    body: "A shared journey has ended."
  },
};

exports.newEntry = functions.database.ref('/StartedJourneys/{fireUserID}')
  .onWrite(event => {
    const original = event.data.val()
    console.log(original.SharedWithUserID)
    console.log(original.JourneyEnded)
    console.log(event.data.changed())
    console.log(event.data.exists())
    console.log(event.data.previous)
    console.log(event.params)
    var payload = payloadStart
    if (original.JourneyEnded) {
     payload = payloadEnd
    } 
        
    sharedUserID = original.SharedWithUserID
    console.log(sharedUserID)
    var db = admin.database()
    var ref = db.ref('/UserTokens')
    return ref.orderByKey().equalTo(sharedUserID).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
      const deviceToken = snapshot.val()

      admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken, payload, options)
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error sending message:", error);
    });

    })
   
})
```

```js
"StartedJourneys" : {
    "nFQhaMkjDeSHDAZCklzN7LoGGc22" : {
      "CurrentLat" : 37.543821,
      "CurrentLong" : -122.239187,
      "DestinationLat" : 37.5232217,
      "DestinationLong" : -122.2520166,
      "DestinationName" : "Nob Hill",
      "JourneyEnded" : false,
      "SharedWithUser" : "Lisa",
      "SharedWithUserID" : "mSJoMJPWWBZEnbq8X05BHwrSd2M2"
    }
  },
```

**EDIT: I have reduced the scope of the question in hope of getting a response. Thanks in advance!**

**EDIT: Added screenshot of the 2 console logs triggered by the function. I should only be seeing one of these. 
[Firebase logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdW3D.png)

Comment: As noted above, I've refined the question to resubmit in hopes of getting a response.

Comment: have you found any solution? @LSteele

Comment: @erdemgc, I did. It turns out that when I was writing the "StartedJourneys" data to the database, it wasn't saving all of that information at once. For example it was saving everything but the Destination Lat and Long, and then running through the for loop and then saving those two in a second round. So even though it didn't appear in the database to be saving in separate instances, in reality the code was looping through twice. Therefore it was writing to the database twice, and sending two notifications. A little embarrassing but there it is!

Comment: but how did you solve it? @LSteele

Comment: @PeterHaddad, I put breakpoints in every step of the function to slow down and visualize what was happening.

Comment: @LSteele my problem is that it runs more than once since im saving 3 times in the database so I have under an pushid 3 key:value.  So the onWrite passes more than once but I get one notification which is great but Im not if it is meant to pass more than once

Comment: @PeterHaddad, apologies for the delay. In my particular case, I was having to read data from one node in the database and then save it to another node. Initially I had it all in one method, but the for loop that I was using to read the data wasn't completing before the write was called. I separated it out into two separate methods; the first one to read all the data back, and then a second just for writing back to the DB. Hope this helps!